# Error in Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

During compiling of my asp.net mvc 4 project ( especially i worked on the login page) i got this message:
**

> Error 1   Assembly 'FYPTrackingTool.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'EntityFramework,
>   Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'EntityFramework,
>   Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'  c:\Users\miso\Desktop\coding\FYPTrackingTool_version1.1\FYPTrackingTool.Domain\bin\Debug\FYPTrackingTool.Domain.dll FYPTrackingTool

**

I dont know what does it mean and how to fix it. I am a newbie in entity framework. Is some one able to help me? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assembly `FYPTrackingTool.Domain` requires `EF 6`; however, you are using `EF 4.4`. Update your project to `EF 6` and the problem should be resolved.

[MSDN article regarding updating to EF 6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/upgradeEF6)